# vitrual env co-exist with base env

Tags: python, virtualenv

After creating and activating virtual env. On far left of command prompt it give me (venv)(base) and when I to pip list it gives me list from base environment. How can I get rid of base and only activate virtual env?

Also when I deactivate it it shows (venv) only, I thought it was supposed to deactivate virtual env, no? Furthermore pip list still gives me all list from base.

Using windows 10, virtualenv 16.5.0, and pip 18.1

NOTE: (base) is my main environment

Comment: What is "(base)"? Another virtual environnent?

Comment: base is my main environment, I will clarify. Thanks

Comment: Your "(base)"/main environment should not be accessible after activating your virtualenv. Do you use the `<virtualenv>/Scripts/activate` batch file to activate your virtualenv?

Comment: Yeah I went in and activate.bat